# Use variables from importing file?

Tags: python, python-import

Say I have a variable that helps with a network connection (eg: API access token) that I want to use in a module that I'm importing (for use in expanding on existing functions), is there a way to pass that variable to the imported script without adding a new class or method to initialize it?

eg:

**Script one (performer.py):**

```
import telepot
import botActions # Possibly adding an argument here?

botActions.sendMessage("locationID", "message")

accessToken = "SAMPLE"
```

**Script two (botActions.py):**

```
import botApiWrapper

def sendMessage(locationID, text):
    bot.sendMessage(locationID, text)
    print("Message sent to %g: %t".format(g=locationID, t=text))

bot = botApiWrapper.Bot(sys.argv[0])
```

So is there a way to pass the variable to the second script from the first one, or would I have to define an initializing function that I call after importing the file?

Comment: Did you try `from performer import accessToken`?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. What do you intend to do with that variable in the other file?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That will work on a local scale, but is there a way to do it from the perspective of a module? For example, if I decided to share my code and wanted to release it as a module that would be hosted in a directory different from the potential location of the new user's main script.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying to use that variable to connect to the API from the imported script; I could potentially do it in the local way that coldspeed suggested, but I'm trying to add compatibility for a larger perspective

Comment: What would happen if a module is imported from two different places? (Remember that Python has a module cache, so evaluation only happens on the *first* import of a given module).

Comment: You really should be using objects (or metaclasses) for state management. Doing so will also make it far, far easier to test your code (if you can reinitialize it several times with different options over the course of a single interpreter running a series of tests).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so basically the easiest way is to have an initializing function defined for each individual run?

Comment: @JamesReed, ...sorry? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Basically what was elaborated in the answers to the question; have a function that is called on startup (or set a class) to define the variable instead of using an argument

Comment: If what it's doing is "defining the variable" -- which is to say, updating a value stored at module scope -- that's very much a code smell (that is, something that general consensus in the Python world is a practice that's Doing It Wrong). (That's indeed the entire reason I added my own answer -- the accepted one is ambiguous about what `botApiWrapper.Bot()` should actually be and do, and not all of the possible implementations/interpretations are equally good-practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do something like this is to define an initialization function from the other file. Instead of `bot = botApiWrapper.Bot(sys.argv[0])`, try something like

```
def newbot(arg):
    bot = botApiWrapper.Bot(arg)
    return bot
```

and then call that function from your other module.

Comment: Why a factory function rather than a class?

Comment: Either are fine; but James' question (1) mentioned initialization functions as something he was wondering about, and (2) was focused on the more general "passing arguments to a module", so I wanted to be more general than a class. Not that factory functions and classes are really that different in python.

Comment: That's somewhat my point -- they *aren't* different. Indeed, I would expect your `Bot` to be a class, if someone were to actually implement the example code in a reasonable way; on the other hand, an *unreasonable* implementation of an "initialization function" might be one that modifies module-scoped variables, and being vague in the answer lends itself to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need state to operate, define a class.

```
class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def sendMessage(self, locationId, text):
        print "Using arg %s to send message to location %s with text %s" % \
            (self.arg, locationId, text)
```

...thereafter letting you initialize as many bots as you like:

```
import botApiWrapper

botA = botApiWrapper.Bot("A")
botA.sendMessage("foo", "bar")

botB = botApiWrapper.Bot("B")
botB.sendMessage("baz", "qux")
```